# How to get the coordinates from the actual video playing inside the MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a MPMoviePlayerController playing a video.

My problem is that, video's dimensions change to maintain the aspect ratio and hence many time there is a big black gap between the video's boundaries and that of the Player.
The black gap is horizontal and vertical.

Is there a way I can get to know what is the rectangle the actual video is contained in?
Then I could find out the touch coordinates with respect to that of the video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the proper dimensions / aspect ratio of the movie content, you can use the `MPMoviePlayerController` property `naturalSize`.

---

From the [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
naturalSize
```

The width and height of the movie frame. (read-only)

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGSize naturalSize
```

> ***Discussion***
>
> This property reports the clean aperture of the video in
>   square pixels. Thus, the reported dimensions take into account
>   anamorphic content and aperture modes.
>
> It is possible for the natural size of a movie to change during
>   playback. This typically happens when the bit-rate of streaming
>   content changes or when playback toggles between audio-only and a
>   combination of audio and video.

Availability
Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
Declared In
MPMoviePlayerController.h

---

Now lets assume you are playing a movie that returns `280x150` for its natural size. That results into an aspect ration of roughly `1.87` (width divided by height). Now let us assume you have a screen resolution of 768x1024 (iPad, portrait). If now you wanted to display that movie in the most screen filling way but still keep some of your controls visible, you would use the following calculation for the actual `MPMoviePlayerController.view` height:

`768 / 1.87 = 411` (rounded)

The resulting frame is:

```
MPMoviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 
                                                (1024.0f - 411.0f) / 2.0f, 
                                                768.0f, 
                                                411.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I actually got this property but then height and width of naturalSize were always coming out to be 0.
I came to know that, it was so that because the video wasn't properly loaded when I was trying to print naturalSize on the console.
Now it works fine !
and once again Thanks for the aspect ratio calculations :)

Comment: Right, I should have emphasized that this natural size will be available to you once the content is playable (you will need to wait for that load state) until you are able to read a usable naturalSize.

Comment: Hey, naturalSize returns 0 here me too. I tried with MPMovieNaturalSizeAvailableNotification, but it effects the default movie controllers. Actually it hides the seeking bar. As Amogh mentioned, video is not loaded when I tried to get the natural size. So where to get the natural size and set the height to video frame?